# Hint on Humphrey's Lie algebra Exericse 2 page 110-111

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

I want to know how to show a hint on Humphrey's book *Introduction to - Lie Algebras and Representation Theory*.

> Take $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{sl}(2,k)$ with standard basis $\{e,f,h\}$. Show that $1-e$ is not invertible in $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$ and conclude that there is a maximal ideal $I$ with $1-e\in I$. Set $V=\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})/I$. Further show that $V$ is infinite dimensional and has no non-zero weight space.

The hint is

> Prove that the image of $1,h,h^2,\dots$ are all linearly independent in $V$, using the **fact** that
> $$(e-1)^rh^s\equiv\left\{\begin{aligned}&0&&r>s\\&(-2)^rr!\cdot 1&&r=s\end{aligned}\right.\mod(I)$$

I am OK with the exiercise but would like to know how to show the **fact**. Indeed, I tried to do induction but it turned out that the computation is too awful. Then I tried to find the source paper

> Francis W. Lemire. Existence of weight space decompositions for irreducible representations of simple Lie algebras, *Canad. Math. Bull.* 14, 113-115 (1971).

where he says 'Note that ...'. Because this result seems to be of importance in this area, I think someone here should know the details (indeed I don't do representation theory but I am super curious about it).